# Using keras model fit funcation but get InvalidArgumentError error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I run these codes in google colab. here is the link https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nH3EwTwpPXky4Bi3KtpLCbZugl7tnCr5?usp=sharing

I split the datasets into training, validation, and test sets, all of which are numpy arrays.

```py
# images
images_train, images_validation = train_test_split(images/255.,test_size=0.4,train_size=0.6)
images_validation, images_test = train_test_split(images_validation, test_size=0.25, train_size=0.75)

# labels
labels_train, labels_validation = train_test_split(labels,test_size=0.4,train_size=0.6)
labels_validation, labels_test = train_test_split(labels_validation, test_size=0.25, train_size=0.75)
```

then process these arrays.

```py
# one hot encode outputs
labels_train_cnn = np_utils.to_categorical(labels_train).astype('int32')
labels_test_cnn = np_utils.to_categorical(labels_test).astype('int32')
labels_validation_cnn = np_utils.to_categorical(labels_validation).astype('int32')

images_train_cnn = images_train.reshape(images_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28).astype('float32')
images_test_cnn = images_test.reshape(images_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28).astype('float32')
images_validation_cnn = images_validation.reshape(images_validation.shape[0], 1, 28, 28).astype('float32')

print(images_train_cnn.shape)
print(images_validation_cnn.shape)
print(labels_train_cnn.shape)
print(labels_validation_cnn.shape)
print(labels_validation_cnn[0])

num_classes = labels_test_cnn.shape[1]
```

Here are some outputs that display the array structure.

```
(120000, 1, 28, 28)
(60000, 1, 28, 28)
(120000, 10)
(60000, 10)
```

Here are my model settings.

```py
# define the CNN model
def cnn_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(30, (5, 5), input_shape=(1, 28, 28), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(15, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

then run the model fit function

```py
np.random.seed(0)
# build the model
model = cnn_model()
# Fit the model
model.fit(images_train_cnn, labels_train_cnn, validation_data=(images_validation_cnn, labels_validation_cnn), epochs=10, batch_size=200)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(images_test_cnn, labels_test_cnn, verbose=0)
print('Final CNN accuracy: ', scores[1])
```

finally, I get these errors

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-a4ad461c0c17> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 model = cnn_model()
      4 # Fit the model
----> 5 model.fit(images_train_cnn, labels_train_cnn, validation_data=(images_validation_cnn, labels_validation_cnn), epochs=10, batch_size=200)
      6 # Final evaluation of the model
      7 scores = model.evaluate(images_test_cnn, labels_test_cnn, verbose=0)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50   try:
     51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential_25/max_pooling2d_47/MaxPool' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 685, in <lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 825, in inner
      self.ctx_run(self.run)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-73-a4ad461c0c17>", line 5, in <cell line: 5>
      model.fit(images_train_cnn, labels_train_cnn, validation_data=(images_validation_cnn, labels_validation_cnn), epochs=10, batch_size=200)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 558, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1145, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 412, in call
      return super().call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 512, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 669, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1145, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/layers/pooling/base_pooling2d.py", line 84, in call
      outputs = self.pool_function(
Node: 'sequential_25/max_pooling2d_47/MaxPool'
Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU
     [[{{node sequential_25/max_pooling2d_47/MaxPool}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_37213]
```

I try many ways, but I can't fix it.

---

Update:
there are data which I used

https://github.com/Genius-pig/quickdraw

Comment: You changed the default image dim ordering  in keras and that is why you have this error, simply do not change the image dim ordering.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thanks, it can run now, but the accuracy is quite low. just 0.1. do you know why?

Comment: No, we cannot know "why" with so little information.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I'm sorry to bother you again. what information should I provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error is because [Conv2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D#args_1)  accepts the input data in the form of (batches, Height, Width, Channels) with channels_last data format by default. As your data have channels at first dim, you can mention this in Conv2D layer as `data_format= 'channels_first'`. Also channels_first format is currently not supported by TensorFlow on CPU, so you need to run the code in GPU to fix this error.

```
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), input_shape=(1, 28, 28),
          data_format='channels_first', activation='relu'))
```

[image]

To get the better accuracy , you may need to do few corrections in the code like how you split the dataset. You should try using below code where the accuracy is 93%:

```
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(images/255., labels, test_size=0.4)
x_train.shape, x_valid.shape, y_train.shape, y_valid.shape

#output:((120000, 784), (80000, 784), (120000,), (80000,))
```

Please check this replicated [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/94fb671eac464dffbd34ee0047de9f16/76346563.ipynb?authuser=1) for your reference.